# Django rest framework using 2 BD

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to clear a question, I can currently work with django rest framework linked to a database, would it be possible for me to use 2 databases in the same project (rest framework) to better visualize the databases, without having to create multiple projects? I'm currently testing on msql but the goal later is to migrate to oracle

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two or more databases in one project, you can specify database routers for each app

### Example:

settings.py `DATABASES`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'default_db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '********'
    },
    'secondary_db_name': {
        'NAME': 'secondary_db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '********'
    }
}
```

app1/router.py

```
class App1Router:
    app_name = "app1"
    db_name = "secondary_db_name"

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == app_name:
            return db_name
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == app_name:
            return db_name
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label == app_name or
            obj2._meta.app_label == app_name
        ):
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == app_name:
            return db == db_name
        return None
```

Same file for the second app, but with different `app_name` and `db_name`. After you created all the routers for all your applications, you should specify them in your `settings.py`:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['app1.router.App1Router', 'app2.router.App2Router']
```

If something is unclear, here's the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers)